# log in using fitnesse

Tags: php, http, post, fitnesse

This is a basic HTTP encoding and formatting question.
I need to log in from a RESTFixture to a PHP web service.
I need to pass in the account, username, and password, as POST variables 
just as a login page does.

Wireshark shows that my login page formats it as
`accountNumber=accounttest&username=usertest&password=passtest`

When I do that in the test, I get a POST array of
    `$_POST: Array
    (
    [accountNumber] => accounttest
    [amp;username] => usertest
    [amp;password] => passtest
    )`

That would work but the "amp;" obviously makes it so that PHP doesn't find the username.

Content type is the same for both live and the test.
[CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Here are a few other formats I've tried with results. In all three cases, it fails to parse so all fields end up in one array entry.

input: accountNumber=accounttest%amp;username=usertest%amp;password=passtest

Result:  $_POST: Array
(
    [accountNumber] => accounttest%amp;username=usertest%amp;password=passtest
)

input: accountNumber=accounttest;username=usertest;password=passtest
 `Result:  $_POST: Array
(
    [accountNumber] => accounttest;username=usertest;password=passtest
)`

input: accountNumber=accounttest%26username=usertest%26password=passtest
 Result:  $_POST: Array
(
    [accountNumber] => accounttest&username=usertest&password=passtest
)

So the last one correctly converts the %26 to &, but doesn't break the items apart
into array elements.

Comment: Try leaving out the amp; (i think you wanted &amp; anyways...), it automatically concatenates post values  with the ampersands

Comment: Then I get  
input: accountNumber=accounttestusername=usertestpassword=passtest
Result: $_POST: Array ( [accountNumber] => accounttestusername=usertestpassword=passtest )

so it still doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: Also tried
input: accountNumber=accounttest+username=usertest+password=passtest
Result: $_POST: Array ( [accountNumber] => accounttest username=usertest password=passtest )

Comment: could you please post the code that you are forming the post parameters with?

Comment: If I had code I would just add the parameters to the POSt array as normal.  But in this case we are trying to hit the webservice from a Fitnesse test using the RESTFixture.   
For a sample, see http://cloud.github.com/downloads/smartrics/RestFixture/RestFixture-2.0.html
and search for 'urlencoded'

Comment: The data seems to be making it into the webservice correctly as I can print out the input I'm getting using these lines
`    $params = file_get_contents("php://input");
    echo '<pre> $_POST: '.print_r($_POST, TRUE).'</pre>';
    echo '<pre> $params: '.print_r($params, TRUE).'</pre>';`
and see what is in the input and the POST array.  When parsing the &, it is breaking in the right place, but then it seems to be URLEncoding the & into amp; and leaving it in the variable name.

Comment: from that example in setBody it uses:  name=test%20post&data=some%20data  Have you tried something like that?

Comment: That is the format that comes the closest to giving good results.  The only difference I see is that my data doesn't have any spaces in it.

To review, when I pass this

accountNumber=accounttest&username=usertest&password=passtest

I get a POST array of 

$_POST: Array ( [accountNumber] => accounttest [amp;username] => usertest [amp;password] => passtest )

Comment: This page has the answer: http://iflifewereagame.blogspot.com/2012/05/restfixture.html    Solution: Surround the url with !- -! to stop Fitnesse doing any parsing on it and it'll work just fine.

Comment: your original link mentioned that too.